# BigQuery.jobs.create pemission

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, feature-store, feast

I am trying to run a python code to create feature store. When I am running I am getting Bigquery.jobs.create permission error. I checked the permissions for my account with `gcloud iam roles describe roles/viewer` and Bigquery permissions are there.

Now, what mistake I am making and how can I solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to create BigQuery job. At least the account you are using should have "BigQuery Job User" role.

Answer (score 0):

All the required permissions and roles are mentioned here.

- `roles/bigquery.user`
- `roles/bigquery.jobUser`
- `roles/bigquery.admin`

Click [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/jobs-overview) to go to official documentation page mentioning the above for revised roles/permissions.